# Spring Security - empty sessionRegisty

Tags: spring-security

I have Spring Security (3.1.0.RC3) configuration like below, but `sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()` return empty list. What may be wrong ?

```
<bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

<bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter" 
    p:sessionRegistry-ref="sessionRegistry" 
    p:expiredUrl="/sessionTimeout" />

<bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy" 
    p:maximumSessions="1">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" 
    p:loginFormUrl="/login" />

<bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" 
    p:sessionAuthenticationStrategy-ref="sas" 
    p:authenticationManager-ref="authenticationManager" 
    p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="authenticationFailureHandlerImpl" 
    p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandlerImpl" />

<security:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/home" logout-url="/logout" />

    <security:custom-filter before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="reCaptchaLoginFilter" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
    <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <security:password-encoder ref="myPasswordEncoder">
            <security:salt-source user-property="salt" />
        </security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

In web.xml i have listener:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed that using Atmosphere Meteor make a problem. With standard configuration without Meteor sessionRegister works good.

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.MeteorServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>org.atmosphere.servlet</param-name>
          <param-value>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        ...
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I get no errors. Everything works good, only session register is empty.

Comment: Maybe my custom `authenticationSuccessHandlerImpl` need to implement something... I have no idea. I did it as described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html) and [here](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-querying.html), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Running into a simliar problem.

Comment: I'm also running into same problem, guys please post if you got something about this problem